# How to Correctly Format ARN in AWS S3 Bucket Policy for Domain Restriction?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-s3-access-points

I'm setting up a policy for an AWS S3 bucket to restrict access to content based on the referring domain. My goal is to allow access only if the request comes from a specific domain, as part of a paid content reading service I'm offering. I'm using the StringLike condition with aws:Referer for this purpose. However, I'm encountering an error stating "Policy has invalid resource"and "action does not apply". Here's the policy I've written:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:us-east-2:798452194891:accesspoint/vercelwzk/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:us-east-2:798452194891:accesspoint/vercelwzk"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": "https://yourdomain.com/*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a couple of questions:

Is the ARN format in the policy correct, especially for specifying the S3 access point and bucket contents?

I noticed that in the latest AWS documentation, there doesn't seem to be a StringLike field under Condition. Is this still a valid method to restrict access based on the referring domain, or is there a newer, more recommended approach?

Additionally, I'm running a paid content reading website where I need to provide downloadable PDFs stored in S3. Is the domain restriction method the best approach for my use case? My website is hosted on Vercel, and I do not have a stable IP address to rely on for IP-based restrictions. Are there any other common methods I should consider for securely delivering content from S3?

Any insights or guidance on how to correctly format this policy would be greatly appreciated.